# Readonly field syntactic shortcut

Tags: c#, readonly, syntactic-sugar

As we know the code:

```
using(myDisposable)
{
}
```

is equivalent of

```
try
{
   //do something with myDisposable 
}
finally
{
  IDisposable disposable = myDisposable as IDisposable;
  if(disposable != null)
  {
    disposable.Dispose();
  } 
}
```

and

```
lock(_locker)
{
}
```

is equivalent of

```
Monitor.Enter(_locker);
try
{

}
finally
{

  Monitor.Exit(_locker);
}
```

What is the equivalent of `readonly` field?

```
readonly object _data = new object();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A readonly object is equivalent to the intialization without `readonly`.  The main difference is that the IL metadat will have the initonly bit set on the field.

Nitpick: Both your expansion of `using` and `lock` are incorrect in subtle ways.

The `lock` version is incorrect because it's expansion depends on the version of the CLR and C# compiler you are using.  The C# 4.0 compiler combined with the 4.0 runtime uses the `Enter(object, ref bool)` pattern instead of plain `Enter(object)`

The `using` version is subtly incorrect because it looks a bit closer to this in the finally block

```
if (disposable != null) {
  ((IDisposable)disposable).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Jared, do you have any links (or can you expand personally) regarding the 4.0 CLR's switch to a `TryEnter` pattern?

Comment: @Adam, I had the wrong method.  It's actually `Enter(object, ref bool)` and not `TryEnter`.  Eric has a full blog post on this and why it was done  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: +1 thanks for knowledge. i didn't know the equivalent of this in C# 4.0.

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense. I do remember seeing this post, but when you said that they'd switched to `TryEnter`, I was trying (punny!) to wrap my head around why, and whether `lock` blocks were suddenly going to start timing out and throwing exceptions instead of waiting.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one; that is, you can't express a `readonly` field except with the `readonly` keyword.

The `readonly` keyword is a signal to the compiler that the field may only be modified inside the class's constructor.